# Everyone drives a Lamborghini Aventador, what now?

Tags: alternate-reality

Situation: Everyone on earth who owns a car has just had it replaced instantly with a Lamborghini Aventador by aliens who saw our slow transportation and wanted to allow us to go faster.

Question: What would be the impact on the average american citizen if this situation were to take place ?

Comment: This is best suited for the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor) since this is not a question about world-building but rather speculation around a magical event. Voting to close on account of being off-topic.

Comment: Also — a personal reflection — I find questions like this to be entirely lacking in imagination because they assume everyone will just shrug, go about their lives and not care that **aliens have just stolen all our cars**. Aaargh!!! Panic! Mayhem!! Is it the end of times?! Are they some kind of gods? Will it displease them if we do not drive the cars? It is a test; do they want to see if we will fall for the temptation?! Drive the cars! No do not drive the cars!!!

Comment: Insurance prices will go up, as well as hospital bills

Comment: Agreed: this is not a question about worldbuilding. Not even really about alternate reality.

Comment: @elemtilas I'll suggest that this could be construed as alternate reality.  "Drop one rock in the pond, and watch the ripples" is an honored SF approach.  Sure, it'd be more inline with SE if he'd said "This is what would happen, amirite" but I'd be willing to keep this one open.

Comment: @akaioi No, dropping a rock in the pond and waiting for ripples is a **dishonored** and **frowned upon** WB SE approach.

Comment: Dubai reporter: "we interrupt this program for breaking news: millions of Lamborghini went missing..." World response: "marketing again, oh come on..."

Answer (score 5):

A few things would happen straight up:

- Mass panic, as people find a different car parked in their spot.  "Dude, where's my car?"  Did the aliens swap the keys, too?
- Assuming people get into their cars, their insurance and registration docs (if present) are out of date and invalid.
- People living in hilly, snowy areas realize they're not getting far.  They go back to bed.  Expect a baby boom in the mountain states several months down the line.
- Lamborghini and their suppliers strain every sinew to tool up to handle the increased load.  Expect them to grow into a powerful zaibatsu secretly influencing our cyberpunk future.  I mean, honestly.  They've been trying for years, and now we just drop it into their laps?
- The spy-vs-spy game heats up as governments investigate Car Swap Day and look for the responsible parties.
- I presume that the other car manufacturers still have their factories.  The new vehicles coming off the lines will be the new hot stuff, as Lamborghinis are now "Grandpa's Car"...  ;D

Comment: Don't forget all the debates and mutual insults that Democrats and Republicans are going to produce... And there also will be a divide among Republicans: 'God sent those cars to us!' 'No, it is a government conspiracy!' And Democrats will come up with some mumble-jumble about the necessity of thorough investigation and launch a car replacing programme... Republicans will start complaining about government overreach and overspending...

Comment: @Olga Dems and Reps will be paralyzed by spin analysis.  No, it is time for conspiracy theorists to step up.  Tinfoil hat people, **THIS IS YOUR HOUR!**

Answer (score 3):

Within a few weeks or months, a complete breakdown of personal transportation and a widespread breakdown of society.

People have a car they do not know how to drive, so plenty of breakdowns as gearboxes are grinding, engines overheat, etc. Mechanics don't know how to maintain and repair them.

Spare parts will not be available in sufficient numbers.

Many people cannot afford the gas these things guzzle.